# 'ambiguous reference' errors when configuring a many-to-many relationship in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-design, entity-framework-core

This is the first question I've asked on Stack Overflow, so I hope it's clear and easy-ish to follow.

I'm very new to Entity Framework and am using it to create my first complex database for my web application project.
I have a few mini-questions that fall under the same category of configuring a many-to-many relationship between the Article and Author classes below.

```
public class MainContext : DbContext
{
    public MainContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Article> Article { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Author> Author { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Author>()
            .HasMany<Article>(Author => Author.Articles)
            .WithMany(Article => Article.Authors)
            .Map(Author_Article =>
            {
                Author_Article.MapLeftKey("AuthorId");
                Author_Article.MapRightKey("ArticleId");
                Author_Article.ToTable("Author_Article");
            });
    }
}
```

As you can see, my initial attempt for configuring this relationship involves overriding the OnCreatingModel method and supplying an instance of the DbModelBuilder class. However, once I add the `System.Data.Entity` reference for the DbModelBuilder class, the error:

> --- is an ambiguous reference between System.Data.Entity and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

appears for `DbContext`, `base`, `DbSet<Article>` and `DbSet<Author>`.

So next, I tried removing the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` reference, and the 'ambiguous reference' errors disappeared. But then I obviously got the

> The type or namespace name 'DbContextOptions' could not be found

error, so I added the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` reference back.

After that, I tried using the ModelBuilder instead of DbModelBuilder class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
```

but then got the error:

> Error  CS1061  'CollectionCollectionBuilder<Article, Author>' does not contain a definition for 'Map' and no accessible extension method 'Map' accepting a first argument of type 'CollectionCollectionBuilder<Article, Author>' could be found

A tutorial I'm using to set up the many-to-many relationship (https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) uses the DbModelBuilder class, like other tutorials I've seen. However, the tutorial doesn't use DbContextOptions - it passes the connection string to the base constructor (I think):

```
public SchoolDBContext() : base("SchoolDB-DataAnnotations")
    {
    }
```

So maybe I should adopt this approach, and use the DbModelBuilder class? Though I've only ever learned how to set the database up with DbContextOptions, and ConfigureServices in Startup.cs, so I'm not sure if this could work for my situation.

From this MSDN documentation for the ModelBuilder class:

> You can use ModelBuilder to construct a model for a context by overriding OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder) on your derived context. Alternatively you can create the model externally and set it on a DbContextOptions instance that is passed to the context constructor

I thought about trying the second method, of creating the model externally. I'm not sure how to go about that just yet, but that could prove to be a better approach to overriding the OnModelCreating method.

To summarise, the main questions I have are:

1. How can I overcome the 'ambiguous reference' errors when using the DbModelBuilder class?
2. What is the difference between the ModelBuilder and DbModelBuilder classes, and when should each be used?
3. Any other suggestions/constructive criticism for my situation, code, approaches... and question-asking? ;)

Thank you for taking the time to read through this mountain of words! I hope it all makes sense, and thanks in advance for any solutions you can offer.

Comment: It looks like you have references to EF Core *and* a .Net Framework EF version such as EF 6 as well. First check your Nuget references and if there is a Reference to EF 6 or such. This will be labelled as "Entity Framework", remove that and just leave the EF Core reference. (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore) )Make sure any examples and such you are using are for the same EF version you are using.  The namespaces for the two versions are similar but vary a bit, and flavours of many classes exist in both under different namespaces.

Comment: Thank you - I removed the Entity Framework package, but then got the 'type or namespace DbModelBuilder could not be found' error, which suggested that I either add a reference to Entity Framework (DbModelBuilder uses System.Data.Entity) or change DbModelBuilder to ModelBuilder (which gives me the error about the 'Map' method).

Comment: @TheaUttley EF Core fluent APIs (and many other things) are different than (even similar named) EF6 ones. Try familiarize yourself with EF Core starting from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/. Also worth reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/

Comment: Yes, the reference for the Many-to-Many mapping you were using with `.Map` was for EF6. EF Core does not use that method and instead expanded the capabilities of methods like `HasForeignKey` to work out complex relationships better, as well as things like Shadow Properties. (Another common use for `Map` in EF6) Have a look at (https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration) for an example of Many-to-Many mapping with EF Core.

Comment: I understand the differences between EF6 and EF Core a lot better now, after playing around with things and reading the documentation - my problem was trying to use a mixture of EF6 and EF Core, but now I'm sticking to just EF Core and things seem to be working. Thanks for the replies!